# How to properly handle child action exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, error-handling

I have an Action that returns a PartialView:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult TabInfo(int id, string tab)
{

    ViewBag.Jobid = id;
    ViewBag.Tab = tab;

    var viewModel = _viewModelManager.GetViewModel(tab, id);

    return 
        PartialView(string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Index.cshtml", tab), viewModel);

}
```

The `_viewModelManager` returns a view from a Dictionary. If a user requests a tab that does not exsist then a `KeyNotFound` Exception will be thrown, however, In my view I get the following Exception:

`Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'`

```
@using MyApplication.UI.Helpers.Html
@model MyApplication.UI.Models.MyJobModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<p>@Model.Blah</p>

...

*@ HttpException occurs here -- renders default error view *@
@Html.Action("TabInfo", new { id = ViewBag.Jobid, tab = ViewBag.Tab })
```

[According to MS...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

> The HandleErrorAttribute attribute on a child action method is ignored if an exception occurs in the child action itself. Therefore, a child action should handle its own exceptions. If a child action has an AuthorizeAttribute attribute applied, the attribute will execute and return an HTTP Unauthorized 401 status code.

I can't user this `[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(KeyNotFoundException), View="myError")]` and I can't redirect using a try/catch either because redirects for child actions are not supported.

**What is the best way to handle child action exceptions?**

Bottomline: I want to handle the exception and return a custom error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this question.

I ended up using a try/catch block to catch the KeyNotFound exception. I log the error and then redirect the user to an ErrorView. In the error view I redirect the user to the appropriate view using javascript.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult TabInfo(int id, string tab, string jobno)
    {
        try
        {
            var viewModel = _viewModelManager.GetViewModel(tab, id);

            ViewBag.Jobid = id;
            ViewBag.Tab = tab;

            return PartialView(string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Index.cshtml", tab), viewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

    }
```

Error View

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/400.htm")';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If an exception is thrown in the `GetViewModel` method then your return statement won't even get processed, in fact it as there's no catch statement you'll end up in `Application_Error` in global.asax (if there you have one of course).
2. You're right you should do a `ContainsKey` check, then if it's false return your error page.
3. Just put the result on `ContainsKey` in a variable and `Assert` that the variable is true? Or you could check on the `viewModel` variable and `Assert` that if `ContainsKey` was false, then make sure your error view name is in fact in `viewModel`.

A `try` `catch` wouldn't really be great practice as in general terms, if you can avoid it, you should prevent the exception happening using additional logic (like `ContainsKey` in this instance). Exceptions are for **exceptional** circumstances :).

Comment: Well the method returns a viewmodel of a base type that I created, so I won't be able to return a view -- I guess I would have to throw the error myself and let the HandleError attribute take care. Any idea why the HandleError attribute is not returning my custom error view?

Comment: Ah okay, is HandleError not returning it locally? By default, HandleError does nothing when running under the local development server. The intention is to show developers more useful information

Comment: +1 for taking a look and providing an answer. Can you confirm the update to my question and update your answer or give let me know how I can troubleshoot further?

Comment: @Rich No problems, why don't you change your `HandleError` attribute to take the base `Exception` (`ExceptionType = typeof(Exception`). Your attribute isn't catching the `HttpException` because it's currently configured to only handle a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: That didn't work either. The Http Exception in the view keeps bubbling up and resulting in the mvc template error view being shown instead. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Rich Have a look at what happens in your `Application_Error` in global.asax. Try redirecting to your error action in there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I add a ModelState error in the child action(with a custom message rather than the Exception's message), and put a ValidationSummary in the partial view for the child action.  Since the parent action's summary doesn't get the errors, then it doesn't duplicate errors.  Of course this still displays the page.  In my case it was perfectly fine.

But you'd want to make sure that you aren't doing something like this in child action `return PartialView(modelContainingPotentiallySensitiveInfo)`.  I can't imagine specific scenarios, but usually the reason you direct to a totally different error page is to prevent error related security breaches in the first place.  So if you use my technique, make sure you create a new empty model, one that you haven't queried from the database, to pass to the partial page.

Of course if an exception occurs on the call to PartialView, something like an error in the cshtml, then you can't return the action and display the error.  So it's not a perfect solution, but might suffice for others.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgot about this one. I provided my own answer with the workaround I ended up using.